# Is there any 'ignite function' to extract date form the timestamp?

Tags: datetime, ignite, sql-date-functions

I am looking for extraction of time and date from given timeStamp 
`(Mar 2, 1019 12:00:00 AM)` using ignite function.

This is query i was working on  :

```
select PARSEDATETIME('02-2019-03','d-yyyy-MM')
```

output of which is a timeStamp in ignite specified format i.e `Mar 2, 2019 12:00:00 AM..` which is fine.

now m trying to find out some ignite function if i can **extract date and time from it**

Comment: No,Not this time

Comment: Also, please use `apache` tag only for programming questions relating to the Apache HTTP Server, do not use this tag for questions about other Apache Foundation products.

Answer (score 1):

Ignite's functions are mostly inherited from H2 (used as query parser and planner), so:

[`EXTRACT()`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#extract) and `FORMATDATETIME()` should be your friends.